# Why does RViz segfault sometimes when I ctrl-c the process?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just the title, really.

It doesn't seem to effect anything when I see the segfault being reported, but it doesn't seem like it should happen.  Moreover, when I close the RViz window using the (x) button in the top left, Ubuntu sometimes tells me "Sorry, RViz has crashed!" when I, well, made it 'crash'...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213660/why-does-rviz-segfault-sometimes-when-i-ctrl-c-the-process?/) by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 350 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably a bug in rviz or one of the rviz plugins you're using.

Without capturing one of these segfaults in an instance of `gdb` and getting a traceback or getting a core dump from Ubuntu, it's pretty much impossible to say why.

If you can reliably reproduce the issue then you can report it on the [rviz issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1